# Load fetched data from the server into input text form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, asp-classic

I use this code to load data into my textarea:

```
$('.content_container').load("minimum_price.asp");
```

But when I try to load data into my input text form with this code:

```
$(".items").find("input[name^=Price]").load("minimum_price.asp");
```

the ASP file returns the result value using this code:

```
if(minPrice <> "") then
    minPrice = CLng(minPrice)
    Response.Write(minPrice)
end if
```

Nothing happens.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because jquery load load inside of your html element.
You need to do something like that :

```
$.get("minimum_price.asp", function(res){
 $(".items").find("input[name^=Price]").val(res);
});
```